# Azure Blob Store SAS token missing Service Resource field

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage

I created a Shared Access Signature(SAS) token on my Azure storage account using the web interface. The token looks like

> ?sv=xxxx-xx-xx&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rl&se=xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ&st=xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

The SAS token here is missing the `sr` field for Service Resource. I have to manually prepend the `sr=b` to the query string to get things to work. I must be doing something wrong, because this seems extremely finicky.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
sas_token = "?sv=xxxx-xx-xx&ss=b&srt=sco&sp=rl&se=xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ&st=xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ&spr=https&sig=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
sas_token = "?sr=b&" + sas_token[1:]

serv = BlockBlobService(account_name='myaccount', sas_token=sas_token)

for cont in serv.list_containers():
    print cont.name
```

Without the `sas_token = "?sr=b&" + sas_token[1:]` I get the error:

> sr is mandatory. Cannot be empty

And if the `sr=b` field is not first in the query, I get an authentication error like

> Access without signed identifier cannot have time window more than 1 hour

Comment: What version of Python SDK are you using?

Comment: I'm using python 2.7.6 and azure-storage 0.34.3

Answer (score 10):

> Access without signed identifier cannot have time window more than 1 hour

Based on this error message, you may need to set expiry time **less than** 1 hour from now. See [Windows Azure Shared Access Signature always gives: Forbidden 403](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17558365/windows-azure-shared-access-signature-always-gives-forbidden-403?answertab=votes#tab-top).

---

I took your code with `Python v2.7.12` and [@azure-storage-python v0.34.3](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python) (the latest version). And it worked well on my site. So, I'd recommend you upgrade to latest version and try it again.

[image]

**UPDATE:**

I traced the [code of Azure Storage SDK for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-python/blob/master/azure/storage/_auth.py#L123) and here's what I found. The SDK is a REST API warpper which assumes that the SAS token looks like this:

```
sv=2015-04-05&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rl&se=2015-09-20T08:49Z&sip=168.1.5.60-168.1.5.70&sig=a39%2BYozJhGp6miujGymjRpN8tsrQfLo9Z3i8IRyIpnQ%3d
```

As you can see, the token doesn't include `?`. And the SDK will append `?` before the SAS token when it makes a GET request to the Azure Storage REST service.

[image]

This would cause that the key of the signed version was parsed as `?sv`, then it raised the issue. So, to avoid this, we should remove the `?` from the SAS token.

Comment: The code as above does work. My issue is that modifying the SAS token seems like the wrong approach. I should be able to use the unmodified SAS token to authenticate and query against an Azure storage account.

Comment: Just remove the `?` from the SAS token. I've updated my answer with details.

Comment: This is like the best answer saved my life because I overlooked that double `?`. Would be really great from MS to get a correct malformed url error or something useful.

Comment: For some reason, it seems that the format of the SAS token you get from the Azure Portal (web UI) is different depending on whether you get a Token for the storage account or for a blob container - the former has a `?` at the start, the latter does not. As a result, if you're using this in a script (for example) you need to check whether there is a `?` at the beginning of the token you are using.